# How can I create a table over several pages with enumeration over several cells?

Tags: tables, longtable, enumerate, enumitem, tabu

I just started using latex and it has a pretty steep learning curve i gotta admit.

I'm trying to create a table as seen below, where the titles in the blue cells are enumerated. I dont need the color but I need the frames around it.

Under the blue title cells i would also like to have an enumaretion over multiple cells with maybe another enumaretion in the cell itself.

The right column stays empty and is for signing in by hand, its supposed to be some sort of checklist.

I have tried several different approaches but I'm stuck now.
I tried with longtabel, tabu, tabular, booktabs. But im not getting anywhere. A big problem for me is the enumeration.

The tablewidth should spread over the whole pagewidth.

[image]

any help or tips are much appreciated. Thank you very much!

edit: added code example.

Sadly I dont really have any workig code, since I always deleted what didnt work as I intended. The fbox is only to see how the width of the minipage is changed.

```
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\begin{tabu}
to \textwidth {|X[10] | X | }
\hline
\multicolumn2{|l|}{a Preflight} \\
\hline
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.5\hsize}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item asdd
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{minipage}

Engine start & \\
}    
\hline  
\end{tabu}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX stackexchange. Could you edit your post to include a minimal working example showing what you have tried?

Comment: Do you really want a table? Wouldn't it be better to have a list? If your concern is to have the entries of the highest level filled with some background color, I think that is doable. If you *really* need a table, you can use `longtable`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I dont really need a table. But i kinda need the empty fields on the right side. So this lead me to the table approach

Comment: @AlainRemillard added a kinda working example. but i deleted most of the code when i wasnt happy with it

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the `enumitem` package, it does have a key `rightmargin` for that (I think).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat so i tried it with the enumitem packge with the right margin, but how can i add an additional box on the right of the list?

Comment: It depends on what you wish to do with that box. If you only want to have the lines of the box, it will be easier than if you need to put stuff in. I feel you will greatly benefit from making the question more precise such that those who consider writing an answer know all requirements precisely.